Nginx rewrite rules for multiple usernames
We require an nginx rewrite rule for our configuration.
What we we need is below.
testdomain1.com/testuser => testdomain2.me/index.php?u=testuser

We need a rule that when a user uses the URL:-
testdomain2.me/index.php?u=testuser

It then redirects to:-
testdomain1.com/testuser

As we will be using this for multiple usernames ( testuser ) we need it so that any username after the testdomain2.me/index.php?u=........  get redirected to the testdomain1.com/whateverusername
I hope all that makes sense.
Thank you
We have this using apache httacess
RewriteRule ^index/u/(.*) /index.php?u=$1


But as we use nginx in production we need the nginx rewrite rule.
